# Javascript show different text content based on lin

Tags: javascript, url

So I have this quiz with two separate start files. Then I have javascript that takes the url argument `?type=ohs` and `?type=dls` and display certain images depending on the argument. I then have a complete page. People with the `?type=dls` argument get a link that takes them somewhere else, and people with ohs get just some confirmation text. I want it to be contained on the same complete page, but I am having a hard time trying to figure it out. The javascript I have is:

```
function go_to_url(page_name) {
  location.href = page_name + "?" + location.href.split('?')[1];
}
```

That is to display images depending on the url argument. How do I create the javascript for the complete page that will display certain text or a link depending on the url arguments ?type=ohs and `?type=dls`?

Comment: what exactly is your question? do you want us to write the code for the whole site, or..?

Comment: No I am just lost. I have two start pages and 5 of the same HTML pages. Depending on the start page it attaches a url argument, and displays different images. I have one complete page that gets one of the two arguments attached to it. Depending on the URL argument for the complete page, I want to display 2 different types of text depending on the argument of the complete page. How exactly do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get values from the query string

here is a function to do that:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Taken from the answer to this question
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

```
var v = getParameterName("type"); //Will return ohs or dls
if(v == "ohs")
    //display text for ohs
else
    //display text for dls
```

Comment: I already have a function that attaches the correct url arugment (either dls or ohs). Theres only one complete page but two arguments, say www.complete.com?type=ohs and complete.com?type=dls. For dls I want to display a specific text and for ohs another type of text.

Comment: This function doesnt attach a url argument it gets it's value, running getParameterName("type") in www.complete.com?type=ohs will return ohs and it will return dls in www.complete.com?type=dls

Comment: Oh okay, so how to I display the text depending on the OHS or DLS in the url argument?

Comment: I don't understand what you want, you want us to show you how to do an if statement? You want us to show you how to display text?

Comment: I guess so. I need to display text depending on the ?type=ohs or dls in the url. I am completely new to javascript, but our homework is crazy complicated and Ive spent hours and cant find an answer.

Comment: This site is more for specific questions. Try to do your homework and ask if you get stuck with a technical detail. There are many ways to do what you are asking, too many. You are asking 3 questions how do I get query string values (I already answered that), how do I do an if statement on a string (it's pretty simple, I did add it to my answer) and last how do I display text from javascript? (a quick search on google will answer that)